# 'int' object is not callable Error

Tags: python, sorting

```
t=(input()).rsplit(' ')
t1=int(t[0])
t2=int(t[1])
k=[]
for i in range(0,t1):
    k.append(input().rsplit(' '))
k6=int(input())
for i in range(0,t1):
    k[i][k6]=int(k[i][k6])
k.sort(key=k6)
for i in range(0,t1):
    for j in range(0,t2):
        print(k[i][j],end=' ')
    print()
```

So I was solving a problem related to sorting and came by this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    k.sort(key=k6)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please can anyone help me with this.
The question is this [Question](https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/8203-python-sort-sort-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1442671240&Signature=Xhd3JWwVfN7maARBP3t7OXlIp8E%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dpython-sort-sort-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf)

Comment: Instead of linking to external resource explaining the question, you should explain it here what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: `key` for sort method must be callable i.e a method. `k6` is integer.

Comment: Not only this, I got another one: ``13 col 1 error| E0602 undefined name 'j' [pyflakes]``

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes. This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.

For example:

```
student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
]

sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

So basically what you can do is to write a lambda function like this. Though you have to fix several issue to get the expected result.